# I am not able to add attributes in forms.PasswordInput all the other input types like TextInput, EmailInput etc work perfectly fine

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am not able to add attributes in forms.PasswordInput all the other input types like TextInput, EmailInput etc work perfectly fine. There is no error when I run the code but the attributes on password fields on my form doesn't show up.

```html
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"u-full-width", 'id':"user_name", 'placeholder':"uniqueusername"}),
            'first_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"u-full-width", 'id':"first_name", 'placeholder':"John"}),
            'last_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"u-full-width", 'id':"last_name", 'placeholder':"Smith"}),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':"u-full-width", 'id':"email", 'placeholder':"johnsmith@example.com"}),
            'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':"u-full-width", 'id':"password1", 'placeholder':"Password"}),
            'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':"u-full-width", 'id':"password2", 'placeholder':"Confirm Password"}),
        }
```

Following is a part of my html code, this is inside the form tags

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <label for="password1">Password</label>
        {{form.password1}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <label for="password2">Re-Enter Password</label>
        {{form.password2}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it working when you are not using the widget?

Comment: It's working fine in terms of functionality, but I am not able add the attributes like I am able to for other fields